# Как разместить 3 блока равномерно?

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, я только учу html и css, взял из интернета рандомный psd, чтобы попробовать его сверстать и никак не могу понять как можно разместить 3 блока так, чтобы каждый из них был ровно по середине 1/3 экрана по горизонтали, вне зависимости от разрешения? Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вариант с `flex`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.333%; /* Можно задать любую другую ширину блока */
  background: grey;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```

Пример `table`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.333%; 
  background: grey;
  border:1px solid #333;
  display: table-cell;
}

.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```

Пример с `float`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.333%; 
  background: grey;
  border:1px solid #333;
  float: left;
}

.row {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```

Пример с `inline-block`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col-3 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.333%; 
  background: grey;
  border:1px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
}

.row {
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
  <div class="col-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Примерно вот так.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-3 {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100px;
}

.border-box {
  border: 1px solid #555555;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="col-3"><div class="border-box"></div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="border-box"></div></div>
  <div class="col-3"><div class="border-box"></div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Вариант с таблицей

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
}

.grid td {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="grid" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td>блок1</td>
    <td>блок2</td>
    <td>блок3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

2) Вариант с flexbox

```css
#flexbox {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#flexbox .item {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox">
  <div class="item">e</div>
  <div class="item">e</div>
  <div class="item">e</div>
</div>
```

При этом ширина здесь не указывается тем самым можно **разместить и больше 3x**